# Django fetching data with HttpOnly cookie says 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have been trying to use HttpOnly cookie with Django for two days but couldn't solve it yet. I tried adding all of these to my settings.py file

```
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True

SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/;HttpOnly'

LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY=True
```

My home.html file

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/books/', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'same-origin',
    credentials: 'include' 
}).then(function(response) {response.json()}).then(
        event=>console.log(event)
    )
```

My api is working and i am signed in but it still gives me "401 (Unauthorized)" response. I searched in google for days and still couldn't solve it. I think i am missing something but don't know what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly set the csrf header.

As mentioned in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true)

You should include `csrf` in your html template when using `CSRF_USE_SESSIONS` or `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` is `True`

So somewhere in your template file add

```html
<html>

  <body>
    {% csrf_token %}
...
  </body>
</html>
```

make sure in your `settings.py`

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ]
}
```

`SessionAuthentication` is first

Then in your template file you need to retrieve the csrf from hidden element and add it to the fetch request headers

```html
const csrftoken = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/books/', {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'same-origin',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      response.json()}).then(
        event=>console.log(event)
      )
```

After this if you're logged in you'll be able to access the desired route.
(Make sure you are logged in into the admin, otherwise csrf will be passed in the request but you'll still get 403)

Comment: let me know if you want me to provide a working code sample for this

Comment: i tried it and still didn't work. Can you give me an example working code ? I feel like i am hitting the stone

Comment: https://github.com/igor-yamshchykov/django-http-only-so-sample
do not hesitate if you have any further questions

Comment: It worked. I found my mistake. Thank you for your help. Really meant a lot to me

Comment: happy to help =)